# Links overlap on snippets

Tags: bug, design, localization, stack-snippets, responsive-design

With certain screen widths, the “Hide results” and “Full page” links on snippets overlap (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56408486/3240681), you need to run the code snippet to repro)

> [image: overlap_en]

Using a smaller or bigger width makes the page look normal:

> [image: small_width]

> [image: big_width]

But even using the full width there’s an issue for localized sites like SO in Russian due to longer words used for links, e.g. [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/987859/176217):

> [image: overlap_ru]

Comment: just use wide screen :)